# Find up to isomorphism all the quotient groups of composition series of a group of order $30$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can't seem to understand what I should do here... 
All I did so far is proving that $G$, (such a group), is not simple. But there are many cases, I can't really tell what $n_2,n_3$ and $n_5$ are, only that each of them is either $1$ proving $G$ is normal, or they are really big, forcing the two others to be $1$. 
I would appreciate your reply.

Comment: I a group of order $30$ they can hardly be "really big". In fact $n_5=n_3=1$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179830 I don't find the question very clear. What is a "quotient group of a composition series"?

Comment: @DerekHolt I think the OP is talking about the composition factors of a composition series. Perhaps the OP is asking the determine such composition factors.

Comment: I think the OP ought to be able to explain the terminology in the question. Why not just say composition factors if that is what is meant?

Comment: The OP quoted in these exact words a question taken from an exam. If the OP had understood exactly what he was looking for, he would have not perhaps be asking this question...